# WebBrowser.Navigate why is it shown in new window when I add Headers

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to load a webpage into the WebBrowser control and I need to pass auth headers.  So I've read that I need to use `.Navigate`. Using VB.Net I've tried this:

```
.Navigate(PageUri, False, Nothing, AuthHeader)
```

This works, but instead of loading the page in the control, it pops out into IE. Now if I change this to:

```
.Navigate(PageUri, "", Nothing, AuthHeader)
```

It loads in the control, but loses the auth details - so the page I'm trying to load pops up a input for the auth details.

I think I need to be able to pass in the frame name instead of "" or Nothing, but I don't know how to access the framename of the WebBrowser control.  Any ideas?

Some other things I've tried for the TargetFrameName are "_blank", "_self", Nothing but none of them seem to help.

Comment: `_self` will open a web page in the current frame (the same Window). Then, it depends on what headers you have set and for what reason. The format also matters.

Comment: The first method doesn't work because there's no overload of Navigate that accepts those parameters. There's no boolean parameter. It simply translates to a wrong frame name. Set `Option Strict On`.